# DataContract objects in client - only simple properties are not getting lost from call to call

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, datacontract

I have this code, a service using a DataContract.
The host is build on a Web site.
Please notice, the serivce is at PerSession mode:

```
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetNewAge(Person person);
}


[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    private int age;
    [DataMember]
    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int AgeNextYear
    {
        get { return age + 1; }
    }
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public int GetNewAge(Person person)
    {
        return person.AgeNextYear;
    }
}

The Client: Uses the type person:

ServiceClient c = new ServiceClient();
Person person = new Person { Age = 100 };
int curAge = person.Age;
int nextYearAge1 = person.AgeNextYear;
int nextYearAge2 = c.GetNewAge(person);
```

curAge - ok.  - simple property works fine.

nextYearAge1  - 0,  instead of 101

nextYearAge2  - program crashes...

Can any one help? Many thanks, Liron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data contract should be a *data* contract. *Logic* like `AgeNextYear` does not get transfered and no proxy class can use that logic.

You could do that if both sides of your WCF conversation were C# and you were using a data contract assembly. Then simply removing the `[DataMember]` attribute on `AgeNextYear` would work because the logic gets shared through the common contract assembly.

Example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    // this is plain data. It can be transfered back and forth,
    // other languages and frameworks will have no problem 
    // building proxy classes for it
    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    // this is not data. There is no data, there only is a calculation. 
    // That's logic. Logic cannot be transfered. Lets say your age is 18, 
    // then this is 19. But the point that this is not a fixed value of 19, 
    // but actually Age + 1, cannot be transfered. It's not data. It should 
    // not be part of the contract if you want this to be usable as a 
    // generic web service.
    [DataMember]
    public int AgeNextYear
    {
        get { return Age + 1; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "data contract should be a data contract" ?

Comment: is it ok to use 'Person' at the clinet at all?

Comment: The emphasis on data is to imply that your data contract class should only be a container of data - No behavior\logic should be a part of your data contract class. And you can certainly use the `Person` class on the client, but in a revised way - Either remove the logic or share an assembly of data contract types on both sides of the wire.

Comment: The technical reason why your data contract classes cannot have behavior\logic when auto-generated from WSDL\XSD metadata is specifically because XSD only describes the structure of your DTOs and not the logic.